# $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is defined as $f(x)=10x+7$. Find the function $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $g\circ f=f\circ g=I_R$

Tags: functions

> $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is defined as $f(x)=10x+7$. Find the function $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $g\circ f=f\circ g=I_R$

---

**My attempt**: $g \circ f (x)=g[f(x)]=f(x)$

Similarly, $f\circ g(x)=f[g(x)]=g(x)$  , since, $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are equal to $I_R$, the identity function.

Now, also its given that, $g\circ f = f\circ g$   $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)=g(x)$

$\Rightarrow$ $g(x)=10x+7$

But that is an incorrect answer.

Comment: How did you get that $g(f(x)) = f(x)$?

Comment: @MattS Since its give in the question that $fog=gof=I_R$ the identity function. (by the definition of identity function)

Comment: How does it follow from what you say that $g(f(x)) = f(x)$?

Comment: Because this is what I've learnt about identity functions, If $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is an identity function then  $f(x)=x$. Am I not correct about this?

Comment: This is correct. Now, how does it follow from what you say: $f \circ g = g \circ f = I_R$, that $g(f(x)) = f(x)$?

Comment: This is what I thought, for example, let $f(x)=y$ then $gof(x)=g(f(x))=g(y)$ Since $gof=I_R$ , $gof(x)=g(y)=y=f(x)$.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. This is simply not a true statement. I don't know how you're equating the statement $f \circ g = g \circ f = I_R$ with the statement that either $f$ or $g$ is the identity function. Neither of them are the identity here. $f \circ g = g \circ f = I_R$ would give you that $f \circ g (x) = g \circ f (x)= x$, and nothing more.

Comment: Now that you have pointed it out, I understand where I went wrong. Thank you for the clarification. @MattS

Comment: You may like to accept or upvote the answers below if any help.

Answer (score 0):

$x=g(f(x))$. But $x=\dfrac{1}{10}(10x+7-7)=\dfrac{1}{10}(f(x)-7)$, so $g(y)=\dfrac{1}{10}(y-7)$.

Perhaps, you can solve $y=10x+7$, and put $x=?$ Then it is the required $g$.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function $g$ which, if you have any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and do $f$ to get $f(x)$, will take you back to $x$. It also needs to be such that if you do this function $g$ first, and then $f$, you get back to $x$.

You have stated that $gof(x)=g[f(x)]=f(x)$. This is not correct.

If for example I had $f(x) = 5x + 2$, my $g(x)$ would need to be defined $g(x) = \frac{x-2}{5}$. You will see that if you compose this with $f$, you get the identity. Can you see how this applies to your example?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f \circ g =g\circ f=I_R$, it is simply asking you to find the inverse of $f(x)$. To do that follow these simple steps.

First write $f(x)=10x+7=y$.

Now switch $x$ and $y$. So you get

$10y+7=x$

Now solve for $y$
Thus $y=\frac{x-7}{10}$.

So $g(x)=\frac{x-7}{10}$